# Bypass required Status Checks in GitHub

Tags: github, github-actions

I am trying to use GitHub Actions to automatically increment the version of my project while building the artifact and check the new changes back into the main branch.

The workflow pushes the commit using a PAT for an account that is used only for this purpose so I was able to exclude that user from the branch protection rule requiring a PR for the main branch.

Because there is also a Required Status check for that branch the push fails with

```
remote: error: GH006: Protected branch update failed for refs/heads/main.        
remote: error: Required status check "build / tests" is expected.
```

How can I have the version commits skip this check while enforcing this check for all other commits?

Comment: Maybe this article about [Handling skipped but required checks](https://docs.github.com/en/repositories/configuring-branches-and-merges-in-your-repository/defining-the-mergeability-of-pull-requests/troubleshooting-required-status-checks#handling-skipped-but-required-checks) could help you

Comment: Unfortunately, that only seems to work with PRs. The direct push to `main` is still blocked because the status checks were never run so I can't trigger an empty pipeline off that push.

Comment: @Silverblaze are you and I the only ones trying to use such a workflow in GitHub Actions? Did you find a workaround nicer than disabling required status checks?

Comment: Possibly, I never got anything to work, so we ended up scrapping the automatic versioning strategy.
I think semver can work great and be reasonably automated using GitHub Actions with a branching strategy like gitflow. The SHAs are probably your best bet for automating the version if you are going trunk-based. It's not what we are currently using, but it is the long-term direction I want to go.

Comment: I sent GitHub a support request about this.

Comment: You are not alone. :)

Answer (score 6):

## 2023-09-01

A recent feature, [rulesets](https://docs.github.com/en/repositories/configuring-branches-and-merges-in-your-repository/managing-rulesets/about-rulesets), provides more control, such as allowing specified actors to bypass status check requirements.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue and tried many different potential solutions. The only thing I could do to get it to work was to create an account with admin permissions, allow force pushes only for that account, not enforce branch protection rules for admins, and then force push the changes (I'm using [this action](https://github.com/ad-m/github-push-action)).

The workflow basically looks like this:

```
jobs:
  update-config:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
    - uses: actions/checkout@v3
      with:
        ref: ${{ github.head_ref }}
        token: ${{ secrets.SERVICE_ACCOUNT_GITHUB }}
        submodules: true
        fetch-depth: 0
    ## do my update ##
    - name: Add and commit change
      run: |
        git config --local user.email "github-actions[bot]@users.noreply.github.com"
        git config --local user.name "github-actions[bot]"
        git commit -m "Bump version" -a
    - name: Push changes
      uses: ad-m/github-push-action@master
      with:
        github_token: ${{ secrets.GITHUB_TOKEN }}
        branch: ${{ github.head_ref }}
        force: true
```

Comment: What scares me about this approach is that a force push would override/revert any pull requests that were merged while this task is preparing to run.

Comment: Yes this is a feature that github should probably support officially, I realize its risky but you should be able to whitelist a user to skip checks just as you can specify users who can skip pull requests.

Answer (score 1):

The solution I found recently, that helps in the implementation of `release workflow` with pushing commits to the protected branch, is to use https://github.com/CasperWA/push-protected.

It does follow the `Require status checks to pass before merging` protected branch setting flow.

The token should have a `Repository roles` [permission](https://github.com/CasperWA/push-protected#notes-on-token-and-user-permissions) granted.
For public repositories, it is a `repo -> public_repo` checkbox to switch it on during the token creation.

Below is a dummy workflow that works for me:

```
name: release
on:
  push:
    branches:
      - main
    paths-ignore:
      - "version"

jobs:
  tests:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
      - uses: actions/checkout@v3
      - name: Runt tests
        run: sleep 5
  release:
    needs: tests
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
      - uses: actions/checkout@v3
      - name: Prepare release
        run: |
          git config --local user.email "user@example.com"
          git config --local user.name "User"
          version=$RANDOM
          echo $version > version
          git add -A
          git commit -m "New version $version created"
          git tag $version
      - name: Push commit to a protected branch
        uses: CasperWA/push-protected@v2
        with:
          token: ${{ secrets.PUSH_TO_PROTECTED_BRANCH }}
          branch: main
          unprotect_reviews: true
          tags: true
```

Comment: This is working 95%. The only thing I've noticed is that if for whatever reason the push fails (i.e pointing to an invalid branch or something), the push protections are not re-enabled, which is very bad. Do you know of any solution to re-enable the push protections?

Comment: hi, If it is possible I would follow this one https://stackoverflow.com/a/77021130/5120554 checked and it works as I expected, cheers

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same problem few days back. In case you're using `standard-version` then in the `package.json` you can do something like:

```
"standard-version": {
    "releaseCommitMessageFormat": "chore(release): {{currentTag}}\n[ci skip]",
  },
```

and in the Github Workflow `build / tests` you can add a condition to skip tests in case a push is tagged with `[ci skip]` like this:

```
if: "!contains(github.event.head_commit.message, '[ci skip]')"
```

[Reference](https://github.blog/changelog/2021-02-08-github-actions-skip-pull-request-and-push-workflows-with-skip-ci/)

Comment: Are you generating the commit as a step in your workflow, or are you doing that locally? 
When my workflow tries to push the commit, even with `[skip ci]`, it's rejected with the same error. I've tried not enforcing the rule on admins and using a PAT for an admin, and that didn't let it through either. 
The only way I've successfully made a commit from the workflow is to remove the required status checks for that branch, but I still want those enforced for other commits.

Comment: I'm generating the commit on-the-fly in the workflow. Without removing the Branch Protection rules, I don't think so there's other way round.